# Recurrence relation of recursive function that contains while loop

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, modulo, recurrence

I have a recursive function `int digit_sum(int number);` that returns the sum of all the digits in the number. For example, `digit_sum(159)` = 1 + 5 + 9 = 15.

Here is the function:

```
int digit_sum(int n)
{
  if (n < 0)
    n = -n;

  if (n < 10)
    return n % 10;

  while (n % 10 == 0 && n > 0)
    n = n / 10;

  return n % 10 + digit_sum(n - (n % 10));
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how to write a recurrence relation for this function. I know that T(0) is the sum of the first two if statement constants. However, with T(n), I am unsure how to express the while loop term and T(n-k).

The modulo operators are throwing me off. This is a guess, and I'm fairly certain this is wrong:

T(n) = c_1 + c_2 + c_3*n (while loop) + (n mod 10 + T(n - (n mod 10))) for n >= 10

I know that the entire T(n-k) term is wrong.

Comment: `if (n < 10)  return n % 10;` is overkill. Use `if (n < 10) return n;`

Comment: You have to return the unit digit plus digit_sum of the number divided by 10 (That is digits shifted) or plus the digit itself if it is the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digit_sum(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return digit_sum(-n);
    if (n < 10)
        return n;
    return (n % 10) + digit_sum(n / 10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("   9->%d\n", digit_sum(9));
    printf("  59->%d\n", digit_sum(59));
    printf(" 159->%d\n", digit_sum(159));
    printf("-159->%d\n", digit_sum(-159));
}
```